# How can I deserialize .xml files along with xmlns-attributes?

Tags: c#, xml, xml-namespaces, xml-deserialization

I am trying to learn deserialization. I have written this code to deserialize *.hbm.xml files.

Every element is loading correctly but "xmlns". The message in the exception is:

```
<hibernate-mapping xmlns='urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2'> was not expected.
```

What should be done to solve this?

You want to see my complete code?

### Here you go:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<hibernate-mapping
assembly="Sample.CustomerService.Domain" namespace="Sample.CustomerService.Domain"
>
  <class name="MyTable" table="MyTable" lazy="true" >
    <id name="ID">
      <generator class="identity" />
      <column name="ID" sql-type="int" not-null="true" />
    </id>
    <property name="Name">
      <column name="Name" sql-type="varchar" not-null="false" />
    </property>
    <property name="MfgDate">
      <column name="MfgDate" sql-type="datetime" not-null="true" />
    </property>
  </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

```cs
public class Class
    {
        [XmlAttribute("name")]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [XmlAttribute("table")]
        public string Table { get; set; }

        [XmlAttribute("lazy")]
        public bool Lazy { get; set; }

        [XmlElement("id")]
        public Id Id { get; set; }

        [XmlElement("property")]
        public Property [] Properties { get; set; }
    }

 public class Column
    {
        [XmlAttribute("name")]
        public string ColumnName { get; set; }

        [XmlAttribute("sql-type")]
        public string SqlTypeName { get; set; }

        [XmlAttribute("not-null")]
        public bool NotNull { get; set; }
    }

public class Generator
    {
        [XmlAttribute("class")]
        public string Class { get; set; }
    }

[XmlRoot("hibernate-mapping", Namespace = "urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2")]
    public class HibernateMapping
    {
        [XmlAttribute("assembly")]
        public string AssemblyName { get; set; }

        [XmlAttribute("namespace")]
        public string NamespaceName { get; set; }

        [XmlElement("class")]
        public Class Class { get; set; }

        public override string  ToString()
        {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(NamespaceName);
            sb.Append(".");
            sb.Append(Class.Name);

            return sb.ToString();
        }
    }

public class Id
    {
        [XmlElement("generator")]
        public Generator Generator { get; set; }

        [XmlElement("column")]
        public Column Column { get; set; }
    }

public class Property
    {
        [XmlAttribute("name")]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [XmlAttribute("column")]
        public string Column { get; set; }

        [XmlAttribute("type")]
        public string SqlTypeName { get; set; }

        [XmlAttribute("not-null")]
        public bool NotNull { get; set; }

        [XmlElement("column")]
        public Column PropColumn { get; set; }

        public string GetColumnName()
        {
            if (PropColumn != null)
            {
                return PropColumn.ColumnName;
            }
            else
            {
                return Name;
            }
        }

        public string GetSqlTypeName()
        {
            if (PropColumn != null)
            {
                return PropColumn.SqlTypeName;
            }
            else
            {
                return SqlTypeName;
            }
        }

        public bool GetNotNull()
        {
            if (PropColumn != null)
            {
                return PropColumn.NotNull;
            }
            else
            {
                return NotNull;
            }
        }
    }

class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //IList<HibernateMapping> list = HbmReader.Get("How_To_Deserialize_a_Hbm_File");
//            string xml = @"<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""utf-8"" ?>
//<hibernate-mapping xmlns=""urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2"">
//    <class name=""Example.Library.Resources.TestObject, Example.Library"" table=""test_object"" lazy=""false"">
//        <id name=""TestId"" column=""TestId"" type=""Guid""> 
//            <generator class=""assigned"" /> 
//        </id> 
//        <property name=""Name"" type=""String"" length=""45"" />
//    </class>
//</hibernate-mapping>";

            Assembly assembly = Assembly.Load("Sample.CustomerService.Domain");
            string[] manifestResourceNames = assembly.GetManifestResourceNames();

            XmlSerializer ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(HibernateMapping));

            Stream stream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream(manifestResourceNames[0]);

            HibernateMapping obj = (HibernateMapping)ser.Deserialize(new StreamReader(stream));

            Console.WriteLine(obj.Class.Name);
            Console.WriteLine(obj.Class.Table);
            foreach (var prop in obj.Class.Properties)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("prop: " + prop.Name);
            }

            string str = string.Empty;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is solved simply with the `Namespace` property on `XmlRoot`, `XmlType`, `XmlAttribute` and `XmlElement` (etc); example shown below:

Output:

```
Example.Library.Resources.TestObject, Example.Library
test_object
prop: Name
```

Xml ([from here](http://opensimulator.org/wiki/Creating_New_Solution)):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2">
    <class name="Example.Library.Resources.TestObject, Example.Library" table="test_object" lazy="false">
        <id name="TestId" column="TestId" type="Guid"> 
            <generator class="assigned" /> 
        </id> 
        <property name="Name" type="String" length="45" />
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

C#:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Xml.Serialization;

[XmlRoot("hibernate-mapping", Namespace = "urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2")]
public class HibernateMapping
{
    [XmlAttribute("assembly")]
    public string AssemblyName { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("class")] // should this be a list?
    public Class Class { get; set; }
}

public class Class
{
    [XmlAttribute("name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute("table")]
    public string Table { get; set; }

    private readonly List<Property> properties = new List<Property>();
    [XmlElement("property")]
    public List<Property> Properties { get { return properties; } }
}
public class Property
{
    [XmlAttribute("name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
static class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        File.WriteAllText("my.xml",
                          @"<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""utf-8"" ?>
<hibernate-mapping xmlns=""urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2"">
    <class name=""Example.Library.Resources.TestObject, Example.Library"" table=""test_object"" lazy=""false"">
        <id name=""TestId"" column=""TestId"" type=""Guid""> 
            <generator class=""assigned"" /> 
        </id> 
        <property name=""Name"" type=""String"" length=""45"" />
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>");


        var ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(HibernateMapping));
        var obj = (HibernateMapping)ser.Deserialize(new StreamReader("my.xml"));
        Console.WriteLine(obj.Class.Name);
        Console.WriteLine(obj.Class.Table);
        foreach (var prop in obj.Class.Properties)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("prop: " + prop.Name);
        }
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Note I've only mapped a few of the xml values - but it should show that it essentially works.

Comment: It fails when I work with StreamReader. Config files are mostly intended to be stored in separate xml-files kept as embedded resources. In that case it gives the famous "<hibernate-mapping xmlns=''> was not expected." message in the exception.

Comment: No, it doesn't. I used a string purely to make it a standalone example, but I'll add a `StreamReader` example....

Comment: @Saqib there we go; updated to StreamReader. If it still isn't working, you are going to have to be more specific in your scenario, as the problem is *in the code you aren't showing us*.

Comment: I have supplied my complete code. I think it doesn't make any difference.

Comment: @Saqib er... your xml doesn't **have** an xml namespace... is it just a case of: add it back? (presumably you removed it at some point). To emphasise: the question cites the message `<hibernate-mapping xmlns='urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2'> was not expected.`. There is NO WAY that your code could generate this, as it can't simply invent that xmlns from nowhere...

Answer (score 3):

The `xmlns` (xml namespace) attribute is reserved to XML.  The XmlSerializer will never return it to you class.

Comment: What should be the alternative way?

Comment: The alternative is to write you own serializer/deserializer.

Answer (score 1):

The serializer doesn't know about the XML namespace since the .NET Type
doesn't declare it.

You need to add the following attributes to make sure the serializer will
consider the namespace:

```
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(Namespace="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute("SupportedAgreementType", Namespace="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2", Nullable=false)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of trying to implement the deserialization automatically, you could use IXmlSerializable.  It's really easy when you get used to it, and very flexible.  You can instantiate readonly properties using the private backing instead of the public accessor, among other things.  It's a little more verbose than attribute mapping, but here's some code you could use (I did things differently here and there to give you an idea of how things work):

```
[Serializable(), XmlRoot("hibernate-mapping", Namespace = "urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2")]
public class HibernateMapping : IXmlSerializable
{
    public string AssemblyName { get; set; }
    public string NamespaceName { get; set; }
    public Class Class { get; set; }
    public override string ToString()
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(NamespaceName);
        sb.Append(".");
        sb.Append(Class.Name);
        return sb.ToString();
    }

    public System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchema GetSchema()
    {
        return null;
    }

    public void ReadXml(XmlReader reader)
    {
        AssemblyName = reader["assembly"];
        NamespaceName = reader["namespace"];

        XmlSerializer classSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Class));

        while (reader.Read())
        {
            if (reader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element)
            {
                switch (reader.LocalName)
                {
                    case "class":
                        Class = (Class)classSerializer.Deserialize(reader.ReadSubtree());
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public void WriteXml(XmlWriter writer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}

public class Column
{
    public string ColumnName { get; set; }
    public string SqlTypeName { get; set; }
    public bool NotNull { get; set; }
}

public class Generator
{
    public string Class { get; set; }
}

public class Id
{
    public Generator Generator { get; set; }
    public Column Column { get; set; }
}

public class Property
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Column { get; set; }
    public string SqlTypeName { get; set; }
    public bool NotNull { get; set; }
    public Column PropColumn { get; set; }
    public string GetColumnName()
    {
        if (PropColumn != null) { return PropColumn.ColumnName; }
        else { return Name; }
    }
    public string GetSqlTypeName()
    {
        if (PropColumn != null) { return PropColumn.SqlTypeName; }
        else { return SqlTypeName; }
    }
    public bool GetNotNull()
    {
        if (PropColumn != null) { return PropColumn.NotNull; }
        else { return NotNull; }
    }
}

[Serializable(), XmlRoot("class")]
public class Class : IXmlSerializable
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Table { get; set; }
    public bool Lazy { get; set; }
    public Id Id { get; set; }
    public Property[] Properties { get; set; }

    public System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchema GetSchema()
    {
        return null;
    }

    public void ReadXml(System.Xml.XmlReader reader)
    {
        Name = reader["name"];
        Table = reader["table"];
        Lazy = Convert.ToBoolean(reader["lazy"]);

        while (reader.Read())
        {
            if (reader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element)
            {
                switch (reader.LocalName)
                {
                    case "id":
                        ReadIdXml(reader.ReadSubtree());
                        break;
                    case "property":
                        ReadPropertyXml(reader.ReadSubtree());
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private void ReadIdXml(XmlReader reader)
    {
        //you can read the attributes and subnodes of the id node as above...
        Id = new Id();

        while (reader.Read())
        {
            if (reader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element)
            {
                switch (reader.LocalName)
                {
                    case "generator":
                        Id.Generator = new Generator();
                        Id.Generator.Class = reader["class"];
                        break;
                    case "column":
                        Id.Column = ReadColumnXml(reader.ReadSubtree());
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private void ReadPropertyXml(XmlReader reader)
    {
        Property property = new Property();
        property.Name = reader["name"];

        while (reader.Read())
        {
            if (reader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element)
            {
                switch (reader.LocalName)
                {
                    case "generator":
                        property.PropColumn = ReadColumnXml(reader.ReadSubtree());
                        break;
                }
            }
        }

    }

    private Column ReadColumnXml(XmlReader reader)
    {
        Column column = new Column();
        column.ColumnName = reader["name"];
        column.SqlTypeName = reader["sql-type"];
        column.NotNull = Convert.ToBoolean(reader["non-null"]);
        return column;
    }

    public void WriteXml(System.Xml.XmlWriter writer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```